# How can I express densities as percentages in R?

Tags: r, statistics, plot, histogram

When I run a density histogram in R, the vertical axis shows densities as fractions. Try this, for example:
`hist(rnorm(100), freq = FALSE)`

See how the vertical axis shows "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", etc. How can I make it display "0%", "1%", "2%"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
x <- rnorm(100)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(x, freq = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
axis(2, at = seq(0, 0.4, 0.1), labels = paste(0:4, "%", sep = ""))
hist(x, freq = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't plot the vertical axis in `hist`. Add it yourself via `axis`.

```
h <- hist(rnorm(100))
plot(h, freq=FALSE, yaxt="n")
axis(2, pretty(h$density), sprintf("%0.0f%%", pretty(h$density)*100))
```

However, this is really misleading, because densities aren't the same as percentages or proportions of something. If you were to do something like

```
hist(rnorm(100, s=0.1))
```

You get the same distribution, but now all your densities are 10 times larger in magnitude because the scale of the distribution is 10 times smaller.

It would make more sense to plot the *cumulative* frequency polygon or histogram with percentages on the y-axis.

Comment: You're right, densities and percentages are not the same thing. In my real case, though, I'll be forcing breaks of width 1, so there won't be a problem relabeling the y-axis as "Percentages". Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio:  There still can be a problem depending on how the density is calculated.